# Importing MySQL to Postgres. Permission issues

Tags: mysql, postgresql, data-migration

I have MySql and Postgres databases. I have been working on Mysql DB which is populated with my data. Now for me to use heroku, I need to port it to Postgres. These are the steps I followed:

I exported data from my Mysql DB by simple dump command:

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

I logged into my Postgres

```
sudo su postgres
```

Now when I try to import the sql into Postgres, it does not have access to db_backup.sql. I changed the permissions for all users and made the dump file read/write to all but still I cannot import the sql.

My question is what is the correct way to duplicate (both schema and data) from Mysql to Postgres. Also why am I not able to access the dump file even after changing the permissions? And if I have a dump from Mysql what are the chances that it runs into the issues while running it on Postgres (I do not have any procedural stuff in my Mysql. Just creation of tables and dumping data into those tables.)?

Thanks!

P.S. I am on Mac-Mavericks if that matters

Comment: And what is the error message that you get? And what was the command that you used to do the import?

Comment: @wildplasser The command that I use is psql databasename < data_base_dump. Error I get is No such file or directory.

Comment: which means that the file "data_base_dump" does not exist, at least not in your current directory.

Comment: @wildplasser The file exists. It is a permission issue. I tried creating the same dump logged in a postgres user it says permission denied for the file. Surely a permission issue. Just the question is how does a postgres user get access to these files

Comment: Even if the file was found by psql you cannot run it. You will first need to convert/replace all the MySQL specific parts from the generated file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So what would be the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: What happens if you use `cat - < data_base_dump` as the command ?

Comment: @wildplasser Permission denied

Comment: What happens if you do `ls -l data_base_dump` ?

Comment: @wildplasser same. As a postgres user it is Permission denied.

Comment: Well in that case the postgres user is not allowed to read/traverse the (path to the) current directory and/or see the files that are stored there. You could try **as the original user** to use: `psql -U postgres databasename < data_base_dump`

Comment: @wildplasser That reads the file. But is full of errors. Any idea how do I create a Mysql dump so that I can run it on Postgres?

Comment: Of course it is full of errors, mysql uses a different dialect of SQL than any other SQL implementation. Maybe mysqldump has a flag to force it towards ANSI-like syntax? Otherwise you'll have to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the primary part of the question was answered by @wildplasser I thought I would put the entire answer for people looking at porting MySQL data to Postgres.

After trying out multiple solutions, the easiest and quite smooth solution was this: https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter

This worked quite smoothly. But just one problem- it does not port any of Mysql sequences to Postgres. This means if you have auto-increment primary ids, you will have to change your Postgres schema separately and create serial sequences after the porting is done. Apart from that, it was quite smooth.

To talk about the permission issue, logging in as Postgres user and trying to access dump created by original user failed, the right way to do it was stay logged in as original user and use postgres user only for DB operation by using -U postgresuser command.

E.g.: `psql -U postgres databasename < data_base_dump`

While for many this must be the obvious way of doing it, I must admit it was one of those eureka moments for me :)